# Why is this Visual Studio post-build event not firing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to copy all of my output files from the solution target directory to a shared bin folder but for some reason the files are not being copied. For some reason, what seems like a very simple post-build command is not working for me.

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir).*" "$(SolutionDir)..\..\..\bin" /Y/I
```

Here's my directory tree:

```
- Development
      - bin
      - Clients
          - Interface
              - Services
                  - bin
                      - Debug
                      - Release
              - Host
                  - bin
```

I need to copy the output from the Services -> bin -> Debug or Release folders to the Development -> bin folder following any successful build.  I have tried various combinations of "..\" and none seem to work.

Comment: What's happening? Is it performing the post-build step but not copying the files, or not even performing the step?  Is it perhaps the case that the build is up to date so the post-build step doesn't get run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I need to trouble shoot post build events
I add an ECHO ON, and generally do a DIR so I can see what directory I am in.

Comment: Using echo did help out.  I was able to see that my target directories were being properly mapped but it still didn't explain why ALL of the TargetDir files were not being copied.  However, I was able to get it working by changing the statement to this:
xcopy "$(TargetDir)project.Services.*" "$(SolutionDir)..\..\bin" /Y/I/f
Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: How does on add ECHO ON?

Comment: The box where the copy command goes, is essentially a batch file.  you can put an echo on prior to your copy command.

Comment: Where does it display the commands that were run?  It's not in the output window...

Comment: @Markus - I do a copy to move some header files to a common location.  I don't see the command, but do see a "1 file copied" in the output window.

Comment: if you copy \*.\*  then it lists the indicidual files copied

Answer (score 3):

These suggestions did not help me.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 (VisualStudio/15.0.0-RTW+2622.4).

No matter what commands I put into the Post-Build Event, they were ignored.  When I closed the Visual Studio session, I was prompted to save my solution file, and accepted this action.

When I opened Visual Studio again, my Post-Build Event commands were gone.  When I re-entered the commands they worked.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19365/pre-and-post-build-events-not-working.html ?

Comment: This kind of thing will happen to me if I have the wrong solution platform or configuration selected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just because someone accidently set the PostBuildEventUseInBuild node as "false".

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <PostBuildEventUseInBuild>false</PostBuildEventUseInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i need to run "npm build" instead of "ng build"

Answer (score 0):

I put the copy action in the "Custom build step" and it didn't work.  Putting it in the build events worked.